# How many items can be stored in a DataGrid

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid

I`d like to store a big number of Items in an AS3 Flash DataGrid (Desktop Application).
The number has a range of 0 to 10k. Does it deal with the PC-RAM or do I have to change some settings? The maximum I can store is about 15 Items.
Hope you could understand my problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you stuffing a prepared `FLVPlayback` object in your datagrid? I don't know what other payload could overload your RAM this fast.

Comment: Don`t know if this is the right way, for each Item I create an Object like var temp:Object = {"Name1":Value1,"Name":Value2}; but just with about 20 values

Comment: I mean if those values are complex objects themselves, then if they are all different, you'll have to spend RAM to store all the structure. And in case there would be an object with several megabytes of `BitmapData`s, or a video, or a preprocessed `Sound` or a similar object, you'll quickly run out of RAM. I say add them one by one, and profile your SWF to find out where do you leak memory.